# Getting File permissions error when exploding the cucumber-jvm.jar

Tags: gradle, executable-jar, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to create an executable jar for functional tests by exploding the dependency jars, using gradle task of type Jar.

Cucumber-1.1.3 is one of the dependencies.
I am using gradle 1.1 with JVM 1.6 (company standards)

I get the following error :

> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not expand ZIP '/dev/shm/263985/transformer/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/info.cukes/cucumber-java/1.1.3/jar/4b389fbe494942b319518d27ae38571f477967f6/cucumber-java-1.1.3.jar'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree.visit(ZipFileTree.java:97)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:96)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$FilteredFileTree.visit(AbstractFileTree.java:136)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree.getFiles(AbstractFileTree.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultFileSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSnapshotter.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.InputFilesChangedUpToDateRule.create(InputFilesChangedUpToDateRule.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CompositeUpToDateRule.create(CompositeUpToDateRule.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$HistoricExecution.calcCurrentState(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$HistoricExecution.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:88)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:128)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository$ShortCircuitArtifactState.isUpToDate(ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:77)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.FileCacheBroadcastTaskArtifactStateRepository$1.isUpToDate(FileCacheBroadcastTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:247)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
>       at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
>       at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:129)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:30)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:22)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:200)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:173)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:138)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy zip entry /dev/shm/263985/transformer/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/info.cukes/cucumber-java/1.1.3/jar/4b389fbe494942b319518d27ae38571f477967f6/cucumber-java-1.1.3.jar!cucumber/api/java/ar/??.class to '/dev/shm/263985/transformer/target/tmp/expandedArchives/cucumber-java-1.1.3.jar_6mn6efsv2arssmg9fup79f3fm5/cucumber/api/java/ar/??.class'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:68)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree$DetailsImpl.getFile(ZipFileTree.java:124)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$1.visitFile(AbstractFileTree.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$FilteredFileTree$1.visitFile(AbstractFileTree.java:145)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree.visit(ZipFileTree.java:90)
>       ... 61 more
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to set file permissions 420 on file ??.class. errno: 84
>       at org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.filesystem.LibcChmod.chmod(LibcChmod.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.filesystem.GenericFileSystem.chmod(GenericFileSystem.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:65)
>       ... 65 more

**Note:** This works fine when you use gradle 1.1 with JVM 1.7.

Let me know if you guys know why this is happening and is there any fix or alternatives.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I wonder why it worked on JVM 1.7 ? Solutions below are not Java related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be encountering an issue we've run into. I'm not sure we 100% understand it, but it appears that when unzipping an archive that has read-only files in it gradle can struggle. Gradle attempts to check the zip against any files it has already unzipped in order to know if the unzipping task is up-to-date, and this process can blow up if the archive has read-only files.

Notice lines like this in your stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CompositeUpToDateRule.create
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to set file permissions 420 on file
```

Not quite a smoking gun, but a pretty strong implication. Our solution (hacky, I'll admit) was to use the following code:

```
def fixExpandedArchivesForLinux() {
    // This interesting hackery fixes the expandedArchives directory
    // to avoid the read-only extracted ZIP file contents issue.
    def dir = new File(buildDir, "tmp/expandedArchives")
    FilePermissions.chmodRecursively(dir, 0200)
}
```

You can put that in a do first to allow gradle to re-expand the archive while it checks the up-to-date status.

Comment: Thanks Josh!! We used a work around by not creating an executable. We created an archive of all jars and used that to execute the tests.

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer. If you found my response useful, feel free to upvote it. :)

Comment: But where is the class `FilePermissions` sourced from? Gradle script says that no such class exists. And I'm unable to find an alternative that might do the same thing.

Comment: I'm no longer at the company where we had that hack (or at a company where we use gradle) and was surprised to find I can't locate FilePermissions online either. You could try replacing that line with something like "chmod -R 0200 ${dir}".execute(). If it works for you I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue when working with android libraries (aars). I got it working by deleting the directories where the aars are exploded.

def str = "rm -rf "+buildDir.absolutePath+"/exploded-aar"
str.execute()

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem involving a file called "??.class" in cucumber.
The exception cause from a run of

```
./gradlew connectedCheck --debug --stacktrace
```

showed the following root cause

```
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException:
Could not set UNIX mode on .../app/build/tmp/expandedArchives/cucumber-java-1.2.4.jar_bkzp93af0tagkjvsr5vkgywjd/cucumber/api/java/ar/??.class:
could not convert string to current locale
```

It turns out that I had a problem with my locale for which I had previously ignored all warnings from other command line tools.
I checked which locales are mentioned in `/etc/locale.conf`, uncommented the corresponding lines in `/etc/locale.gen` and ran

```
sudo locale-gen
```

to regenerate the locales.
After this, the file names showed up like `ਅਤੇ.class` and the unzipping worked flawlessly.