# Upgrading to gradle 2.1.0 causes – Could not expand ZIP error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated my Android project's gradle plugin to `2.1.0` from `2.1.0-alpha4`. But now I see that all my builds fail with a message like so:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':App:compileUpdemoDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not expand ZIP '/Users/admin/work/app/libs/lib-android-0.11.0.jar'.
```

If I revert my gradle plugin to the previous `2.1.0-alpha4` version, set the environment variable `ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE` and then build my project — everything works just fine.

Has anyone else come across this problem? I believe this is related to the latest plugin, and so, people might just start to stumble across this problem.

Any possible solutions? 
(I am aware of some workarounds, like extracting the JAR and making gradle skip the JAR extraction process, but that certainly doesn't sound worth the effort!)

Comment: From what I could find, it may be an issue with the permissions on the jar file. Maybe you can try what is suggested in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16946902/1914223

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't place the `FilePermissions.chmodRecursively(dir, 0200)` used in the method. Gradle says there exists no class like `FilePermissions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, most of the answers posted here didn't work out. Although, logically speaking, @Kowshick's answer seemed to tackle the right thing — i.e, there's something wrong with the directory permissions. However, giving `777` access can't be the right thing, and the default `755` that I had on my development folder, sdk folder, build folder — should've worked just fine. But it *didn't*. :(

Eventually, what I realised is that there are only 3 ways to resolve this problem:

1. Wait for Google to release an update to its build tools, which would update the gradle plugin, and *hopefully* resolve this issue.
2. And while you wait for the above to happen, the *only* thing that worked for me was to downgrade the gradle plugin to version `2.0.0`. The very fact that it works by downgrading, shows that the real issue isn't with the directory permissions I have.
3. Finally, there's this rather frustrating thing you can do — create a separate user on your system, and setup your project from scratch — download Android Studio, SDK and your workspace. There's a good chance it'll work, but it's a horrible way to work. And on top of that, if you don't have an OS which supports fast user switching, you're just going to feel a world of pain.

In my case, I survived using option # 2 for some time, and I was just lucky that I had my hard drive upgraded to an SSD, so I finally ended up doing option # 3 too (since I made a fresh install of my OS on the SSD).

Other info:
OS — OS X (El Capitan)
Android studio — 2.1.0

Comment: downgrading gradle version to 2.0.0 worked for me as well.Thanks a ton

Answer (score 5):

Follow below step to set automatically gradle sync in your android studio.

**File** -> **Settings** -> **Build,Execution,Deployment** ->**Build tools -**> **gradle** -> **check Use Default gradle wrapper(recommended)** radiobutton.

Also follow below step to restart your android studio for invalid cache restart.

**File** > **Invalidate Caches/Restart** (you can also manually remove the cache at ~/Library/Caches/{yourIDEName} and restart the IDE)

Then save settings and rebuild your project.

Comment: Usually, this is like the very first thing I do when it comes to quirky Android Studio issues. But I was facing this issue even when I was building my project from the command line using `gradle assemble`. So, that pretty much implied that the issue isn't with AS, but with the Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see your project is in admin directory
/Users/admin/work/app/libs/lib-android-0.11.0.jar.

1) Either you could try moving your project path to some user directory,like /home/username/

2) Or you could give write permission to you project path by using

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /Users/admin/work/app/
```

Guess this helps.

Comment: All my directories — Android Studio, SDK and work project were under `/Users/username/` only.
Giving a permission of `777` doesn't make any sense. The default `755` should work just fine. Besides, this project is a 2 years old project. So all of a sudden, something going wrong with the permissions doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1.Go to **Help**.

2.**Check for updates**.

Update to Android Studio 2.1.1 by clicking on **Update and Restart**.

Comment: Yeah - that was what it finally came down to. And in the meantime, I simply downgraded my gradle plugin :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after opening on a new PC with Android Studio 2.1.3 an existing projet created with Studio 1.x.
I had to downgrade Gradle version to 2.2.1 and Android Plugin Version to 1.5.0 in the project settings to get back a successful apk build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows:

try to unzip your jar file by hand. In most cases the classes are not case sensitive and as a result windows systems gets trouble.

If you use Windows, you can get more information within this ticket:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207862

Answer (score 0):

Blow away the build directory - if you ran gradle with sudo or as a different user, build directories can have a different use and thus cannot extract the aar.