# Could not expand ZIP error on Chuck android library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I added dependencies as referenced by [documentation](https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck) like

```
dependencies {
   debugCompile 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.0.0'
   ...
 }
```

But when I try to build project I am getting this error below:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:prepareComReadystatesoftwareChuckLibrary100Library'.
>
> > Could not expand ZIP '/Users/yutku/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.readystatesoftware.chuck/library/1.0.0/9b35ca88dde54d309b52db9dccfc0a9486546eaa/library-1.0.0.aar'.

What have i tried?

- Invalid cache and restart
- Update gradle and tools to latest version
- Yes, I already tried this [Upgrading to gradle 2.1.0 causes – Could not expand ZIP error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058173/upgrading-to-gradle-2-1-0-causes-could-not-expand-zip-error)